# Compare three strings in python

Tags: python, string, time, string-comparison

In strings I have data, that represents running race time.
For example, I have one string that I want to compare0 and I want to print string closest to them.

Input time: `37:30`

Strings between that time: `37:31 and 36:50`

So I want to print out `37:31`.

My condition is wrong, because it prints `36:50`

```
for i in list:
    if i <= time:
       print i
       break
```

I don't want to convert strings to seconds.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can transform your list in float and then find the minimal difference. but as said by BoarGules you can't compare string in this way.

Here an example of what you can do :

```
>>> list 
['37:30', '36:51', '37:29'] 
>>> time
'37:28'
>>> list2=[float('.'.join(i.split(':'))) for i in list]
>>> time2=float('.'.join(time.split(':')))
>>> min(list2, key=lambda x:abs(x-time2))
37.29
```

**EDIT**

```
>>> list=['12:37:21', '11:23:15', '12:37:28']
>>> time='11:24:12'
>>> list2=[int(''.join(i.split(':'))) for i in list]
>>> time2=int(''.join(time.split(':')))
>>> out=str(min(list2, key=lambda x:abs(x-time2)))
>>> out=out[:2]+':'+out[2:4]+':'+out[4:]
>>> out
'11:23:15'
```

Comment: Very nice short solution for given time format. But if i have hh:mm:ss format it cannot convert to float

Comment: @KubaRonkiewicz see EDIT in my post

Answer (score 3):

Your test is failing because it reports the first time it finds that is less, not the nearest.

Not wanting to convert to seconds is a problem. You want the smallest distance and that requires computing the difference between the input time and a candidate time. There is no easy way to compute a difference between two strings that will do what you want. What's the objection to doing the conversion?

Comment: Why I don't want to do the conversion? Because I have different time formats for different distance(hh:mm:ss, mm:ss, ss.ms), so I need to write more if/else conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Without converting to seconds, you can compare strings, but can't compute the difference between them. For your case, the difference is relevant as you want to print the closest time. Do something like:

```
def convert(string):
    min, sec = string.split(':')
    return min*60 + sec
```

Assuming your `list` is sorted in ascending order, perform the following check:

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    if list[i] > time:
        if i == 0: # the very first string is greater, so it's also the closest
            print(list[i])
            break
        diff1 = convert(time) - convert(list[i-1])
        diff2 = convert(list[i]) - convert(time)
        if diff1 < diff 2: # lis[i-1] is closer
            print(list[i-1])
        else:
            print(list[i])
        break
```